# Run bash script after Apache2 restarts on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I use Ubuntu 16.04.

I want to add a hook that is invoked once Apache2 restarts and runs a command line (bash).

For example

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=high
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

While not ideal as it is in no way a "hook"... you could write a script to check the status of the apache program and toggle a "switch" variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

s=0; 
while true; do
    /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null;

    if [ $? -eq "0" ] && [ ! "${s}" -eq $? ]; then 
        # Do whatever you want to do when apache first starts running.
    fi

    s=$?
done
```

So we have a `s`witch.  We check the return code of `status` on apache2.  0 Appeared to be when its running, not 0 (3) if it wasn't running.

`$?` returns the status code of the last run command if you didn't know.

`if [ $? -eq "0" ] && [ ! "${s}" -eq $? ];`  If apache is running, but it wasn't running the last time we checked, it just started! Let's do some work.

`s=$?` This line sets the switch to the last status code... means next loop `$s` will actually `eq $?` so the loop won't run.

I highly suggest you add in a `sleep 1` or whatever an acceptable delay is between apache starting and your program running is.